# Angular 1.x + Typescript + Webpack -> reference path= exists in output file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack

I have some issues while i'm trying to compile my angular project from TS to JS. The compilation with gulp-typescript works but Webpack should be used as a replacement for existing gulp tasks

after executing:

`./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --verbose --display-error-details`

I get a javascript output file containing:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />
///<reference path="a/b.module.ts"/>
///<reference path="c/D.module.ts"/>
///<reference path="e/f.module.ts"/>
///<reference path="g/h.module.ts"/>
///<reference path="y/x.module.ts"/>

var app;
(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', ['ngDisableScroll', 'ng.deviceDetector', 'app.testRoutes', 'app.core', 'app.blocks.modifyScale', 'app.layout', 'app.main').run(app.watchForResizeEvent).run(app.watchForChangeVisibilityEvent);
})(app || (app = {}));

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Looks like something is miss-configured!

My configurations:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app/index.module.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[hash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/scripts/")
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".webpack.js", ".web.js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: "node_modules",
                loader: ["babel-loader", "ts-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    // https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/",
        "**/*.mock.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
    "globalDependencies": {
        "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160922195358",
        "angular-animate": "registry:dt/angular-animate#1.5.0+20160709061515",
        "angular-cookies": "registry:dt/angular-cookies#1.4.0+20160317120654",
        "angular-material": "registry:dt/angular-material#1.1.0-rc5.0+20160923175937",
        "angular-mocks": "registry:dt/angular-mocks#1.5.0+20160608104721",
        "angular-resource": "registry:dt/angular-resource#1.5.0+20160914132003",
        "angular-sanitize": "registry:dt/angular-sanitize#1.3.0+20160930125720",
        "angular-scroll": "registry:dt/angular-scroll#0.0.0+20160317120654",
        "angular-translate": "registry:dt/angular-translate#2.4.0+20160729132354",
        "angular-ui-router": "registry:dt/angular-ui-router#1.1.5+20160810191828",
        "angulartics": "registry:dt/angulartics#0.20.2+20160317120654",
        "createjs-lib": "registry:dt/createjs-lib#0.0.0+20160317120654",
        "easeljs": "registry:dt/easeljs#0.8.0+20160919062420",
        "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise#0.0.0+20160726191732",
        "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.5.0+20161003201800",
        "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160929162922",
        "ngstorage": "registry:dt/ngstorage#0.3.10+20160711132043",
        "tweenjs": "registry:dt/tweenjs#0.6.0+20160317120654",
        "underscore": "registry:dt/underscore#1.8.3+20160908111004"
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "version": "3.33.1-SNAPSHOT",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "test": "gulp test"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
        "browser-sync": "~2.11.1",
        "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
        "chalk": "~1.0.0",
        "concat-stream": "~1.5.0",
        "del": "~1.2.0",
        "event-stream": "^3.3.4",
        "gulp": "~3.9.0",
        "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.6.0",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "~2.3.1",
        "gulp-bump": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-concat": "~2.5.2",
        "gulp-css-url-adjuster": "^0.2.3",
        "gulp-csso": "~1.0.0",
        "gulp-dom": "^0.9.0",
        "gulp-filter": "~2.0.2",
        "gulp-flatten": "~0.0.4",
        "gulp-gzip": "^1.2.0",
        "gulp-inject": "~1.3.1",
        "gulp-jshint": "~1.11.0",
        "gulp-less": "~3.0.3",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
        "gulp-manifest": "^0.1.1",
        "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.3",
        "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.0.0",
        "gulp-ng-config": "^1.2.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-replace": "~0.5.3",
        "gulp-rev": "~5.0.0",
        "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
        "gulp-size": "~1.2.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.5.2",
        "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.3",
        "gulp-typescript": "~3.0.2",
        "gulp-typings": "^2.0.4",
        "gulp-uglify": "~1.2.0",
        "gulp-useref": "~1.2.0",
        "gulp-util": "~3.0.5",
        "gulp-wrap": "^0.11.0",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.0.5",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
        "jshint-stylish": "~2.0.0",
        "karma": "^0.13.3",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
        "karma-coverage": "^0.4.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.3.2",
        "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.2",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
        "lodash": "~3.9.3",
        "main-bower-files": "~2.8.0",
        "merge-stream": "~0.1.7",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.3",
        "require-dir": "~0.3.0",
        "stream-series": "^0.1.1",
        "tslint": "^3.6.0",
        "ts-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "~2.0.3",
        "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
        "webkit-assign": "^1.3.0",
        "webpack": "2.2.0",
        "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
        "wrench": "~1.5.8",
        "yargs": "^3.15.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? If you are talking about the `reference-path` comments being present, you can just run a minifier on the file to remove all comments altogether.

Comment: the referenced modules where not includes to the js file. Workaround,  added to tsconfig.json: `"outFile": "index.module.js",
    "module": "amd",
    "removeComments": true` now i got a nice large javascript file.